# Inject console.log() in chrome inside a js file on reload

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I inspected a js function and now I want to add in a console.log() into one of the lines. But I cannot edit this file locally as I'm just visiting the website. How can I inject my own js code even on reload of this page to debug a js function.

Comment: You may be able to accomplish this with [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en). But most likely this function will be called before your script has a change to override it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Local Overrides](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools#overrides). They allow you to edit files on a site and even reload, while keeping your source changes. In the DevTools, head to Sources > Overrides. More details on setting them up here:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools#overrides

Comment: I hadn't been reading the update notes for Chrome. This works great!